# How is passing an anonymous function as an argument internally used?

Tags: javascript, arguments

I've encountered some code that I'm having trouble fully understanding. The principles seem clear enough, but I'm having some difficulty with the second argument that's declared in the forEach function call. Clearly the anonymous function is passed into forEach via the action argument, but how exactly does it work once inside the for loop?

```
function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    action(array[i]);
}

var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sum = 0;

forEach(numbers, function(number) {
  sum += number;
});

console.log(sum); // 15
```

I think what confuses me most is that the syntax of the anonymous function doesn't seem *compatible* with `action(array[i])` - I mean, I understand that `sum` acquires each value of the array in turn, but if the function "replaces" the `action` argument, how and where does the `(array[i])` part fit in?

Comment: I'm confused with your confusion. The `forEach` function accepts two parameters, the second needs to be a reference to a function (any function - named, anonymous, whatever)...you pass an anonymous function. Inside the `forEach` function, it has the `action` parameter declared...and since it **should** hold a reference to a function, and you can call functions, you can call `action`. Calling `action` calls whatever the second argument you passed. And it calls it with one argument (`array[i]`), which is can be used as the `number` parameter in the function you passed

Comment: @Ian - thanks. I knew I was in danger of not explaining myself quite properly, but you've helped clear things a little. I was viewing it as though the entirety of the anon function was held in the action variable, rather than a reference to it. So it seemed that `(array[i])` would succeed the function, rather than act as its argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me rewrite that code in a more explicit way:

```
function forEach(array, action) {   //1st parameter is an array, the 2nd is a function
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    action(array[i]); //The function is used, with each element of the array as parameter
}

var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sum = 0;

var myFunction= function (number) { //I declare a function which receives a number
  sum += number;                    //and adds it to sum.
}

forEach(numbers,myFunction); //I call the forEach function using the
                             // variables I previously created as parameters

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: This is such a simple explanation. Seeing it written this way immediately highlights the errors in my misunderstanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript when you define a variable you write:

```
var x = 0; // here you reserve an object
```

And when you define a function also you reserve an object. Javascript deal with functions as objects and you can assign it to any variable:

```
var x = function(number){ sum +=number; };
forEach (numbers, x(number) );
```

And about the confused syntax, Anonymous functions are functions that are dynamically declared at runtime. They’re called anonymous functions because they aren’t given a name in the same way as normal functions.
So to call an Anonymous function you follow this syntax:

```
// call
function (param1, param2, ...){
// function body
}
```

if you want to call it again either you should repeat the code above or declare a function without calling it and save it on variable where you can call it many times:

```
// declaration
var x = function(param1, param2, ...){
    // body
};
// call
x(p1,p2,....);
```